# ORACLE SQL: how to get text before a specific word

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

Using `Oracle`,

1. how can i get the text before a specific word(CITY) including the word CITY

> Sample:
>
> ```
> 22nd street westlake 1378 california city 
> 32nd street texas 1111 houston city
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> California city 
> Houston city
> ```

2. Removing the city from item#1.

> Sample:
>
> ```
> 22nd street westlake 1378 california city 
> 32nd street texas 1111 houston city
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> 22nd street westlake 1378
> 32nd street texas 1111
> ```

updated the question. thanks

Comment: Would the column always be of the format `NUMBER NAME city`?  Or, could there be other variants?  If so, then please include sample data which covers all edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to remove string or numbers from your string.

Try to use `regexp_replace` as follows:

1.

```sql
regexp_replace( '1378 california city 1111 houston city' , '[^0-9 ]')
```

2. 

```sql
regexp_replace( '1378 california city 1111 houston city' , '[0-9]')
```

Check the complete example here:
[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=17129f260b4c1eff8516bbee0da9554a)